# How to extract a part string from a json response in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have a json response from my server which is "url":"http://abc.company.com/abc-payment-ui/985ed46a-416d-4653-b63d-abaee55563d5". I want to extract the only the last part of the url i.e. after "abc-payment-ui/**985ed46a-416d-4653-b63d-abaee55563d5**" which is the ID i want to use in a request.
Any suggestions guys? I know there is a json path extractor for this but that returns me the whole url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using a regex extractor? It should work very nicely. In your case you should consider something like "abc-payment-ui/(.*)" or something like it.

See some basic guidance here: 
http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html

If you want to read about JSONPath or XPath, this is an excellent article: http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0

Comment: Thanks Alon, this worked...I never had situations where I needed to use regex, but anyways thanks for the help.